# LIRC won't recognise IR commands

Tags: gpio, pi-2, hardware, lirc

I want to control my RaspberryPi B+ 1.2 using a remote control. I did the steps according to several tutorials but I can't get `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` to output any pulses.

#### `/boot/config.txt`

```
[pi1]
kernel=vmlinuz-3.18.0-trunk-rpi
initramfs initrd.img-3.18.0-trunk-rpi followkernel
# to enable DeviceTree, comment out the next line 
device_tree=
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128

# LIRC
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_in_pin=18,gpio_out_pin=17
dtparam=gpio_in_pull=up
```

#### `/etc/lirc/hardware.conf`

```
# /etc/lirc/hardware.conf
#
# Arguments which will be used when launching lircd
LIRCD_ARGS="--uinput"

#Don't start lircmd even if there seems to be a good config file
#START_LIRCMD=false

#Don't start irexec, even if a good config file seems to exist.
#START_IREXEC=false

#Try to load appropriate kernel modules
LOAD_MODULES=true

# Run "lircd --driver=help" for a list of supported drivers.
DRIVER="default"
# usually /dev/lirc0 is the correct setting for systems using udev 
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
MODULES="lirc_rpi"

# Default configuration files for your hardware if any
LIRCD_CONF=""
LIRCMD_CONF=""
```

#### `/etc/modules`

```
snd-bcm2835
lirc_dev
lirc_rpi gpio_in_pin=18 gpio_out_pin=17
```

#### Hardware

I connected both 3.3V and GND and put the signal pin on the GPIO 18 as configured.

I did also test the IR Receiver using an [Arduino Sketch](https://gist.github.com/besi/99ab4d00b5dd538314e7fc0edec7863f) so I know that both my remote and the receiver work fine.

#### System

Lirc

```
lircd --version
lircd 0.9.0-pre1
```

System

uname -rv
   3.18.0-trunk-rpi #1 PREEMPT Debian 3.18.5-1~exp1+rpi19 (2015-08-08)

#### Debugging

Starting and stopping the service works fine:

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/lirc start
[ ok ] Loading LIRC modules:.
[ ok ] Starting remote control daemon(s) : LIRC :.
# sudo /etc/init.d/lirc stop
[ ok ] Stopping remote control daemon(s): LIRC:.
```

LSMOD

```
# lsmod | grep lirc
lirc_rpi                6890  0 
lirc_dev               10683  1 lirc_rpi
rc_core                17686  1 lirc_dev
```

GPIO Kernel Debug
Here I should see the GPIO pins I guess

```
# mount -t debugfs debugfs /sys/kernel/debug
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio 
GPIOs 0-53, platform/20200000.gpio, pinctrl-bcm2835:
 gpio-13  (sysfs               ) in  hi IRQ
 gpio-21  (sysfs               ) in  lo IRQ
 gpio-35  (led1                ) out lo    
 gpio-47  (led0                ) out lo
```

DSMEG

```
# dmesg | grep lirc_rpi
[    0.206481] of_dma_get_range: no dma-ranges found for node(/lirc_rpi)
[    9.332416] lirc_rpi: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   10.496625] lirc_rpi: auto-detected active low receiver on GPIO pin 18
[   10.598135] lirc_rpi lirc_rpi: lirc_dev: driver lirc_rpi registered at minor = 0
[   10.778155] lirc_rpi: driver registered!
```

<sub>Internal Reference phone#46</sub>

[image: GPIO Setup]

Comment: Please add a photo showing the connections to the Pi.

Comment: @joan: You were right about the wiring. I have a sticker on my Pi with the pins and it was flipped so the wiring was wrong all along. You may add an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: It was only a guess.  You can self answer and accept the answer in a day or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my problem was really silly. I had a sticker with the pins in my device and it turned out that the sticker was flipped to that the receiver was not connected to the right pins.

Once I fixed this I would get signals on my remote.